# Django how to track each models fields when it was last updated? or is it possible to use autonow in boolean or char fields?

Tags: python, django

I have a model name CustomerProject and I want to track individually few fields when it was last updated. Right now I am using `auto_now= True` in datetime fields which can tell me when the whole model was last edited but I want to track individually few boolean fields such as when the work started? when the work delivered etc. here is my

**models.py**

```
class CustomerProject(models.Model):
      project_title = models.CharField(max_length=2000,blank=True,null=True)
      project_updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True,blank=True,null=True)
      #I want to track separately those  BooleanField 
      project_started = models.BooleanField(default=True)
      wting_for_sample_work = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      sample_work_done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      working_on_final_project = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      project_deliverd = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      project_closed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there might be three solutions for this.
First one is using simple history library.

https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

It creates a history model for your model and keeps track of all changes. This way, you can check which field is modified when, or go back to that state easily. But if you only want to keep track of the time which this booleans are set to True, this might be an overkill.

Second option would be to add a JSONField to keep track a time for any field you want.
Would be something like that.
{
"project_started": "2021-08-01 15:18:31",
"wting_for_sample_work": "2021-08-03 15:18:31"
}
You can set it in your view (by checking if each field is changed).

Third option would be just change these booleans to DateTimeField.
Then, you can check those datetime fields. If it is set, it is true and vice versa.

I think easiest is to go with 3rd option.